# waiting in server for a massage from client in python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

i want to follow this steps:
1.client send an initiate connection request to the server
2.server accept the request(or not accept)
3.server wait until the client send a `username`
4.client ask the user a name for `username`
5.server after receiving the massge containing the `username` from the client check if it is not exist and the make a new thread for this connection and register the connection.

this is my server code:

```
import socket
import threading

class mainServer(threading.Thread):
    userRegistered = list()
    clntNames = list()

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 14269))
        self.sock.listen(5)

        while True:
            clientConn, clientAddr = self.sock.accept()
            print("Got connection from", clientAddr)

            clientNameReq = ""
            while (1):
                clientNameReq = self.sock.recv(10)
                print("A")

            clientConn.send("REG#OK".encode())
            if(clientNameReq.decode() not in mainServer.clntNames):
                clientThread(clientConn, clientAddr, clientNameReq)
```

the rest of code is removed!
and this is client code:

```
import threading
import socket
import sys
servername = '127.0.0.1'
class mainClients(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, HOST, PORT):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = threadID
        self.port = PORT
        self.host = HOST
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        except:
            print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise
        clientName = input("Please enter your username:")
        RegReq = "REG#EMAD"
        self.sock.send(RegReq.encode())
        RegReqResp = self.sock.recv(1024)
    if (RegReqResp.decode()=="REG#OK"):
        print("Ok Shod")
mainthread = mainClients(1, servername, 14269)
```

i get `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected` error for line 21 ( clientNameReq = self.sock.recv(10) ) from server code.
in that line i want from server to wait until a massage come from the client.

Comment: I suppose that you need break from your infinite loop on empty sock.recv. You are trying to read infinitely even when socket closed by client.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here.

**First one**. When a client connects (`clientConn, clientAddr = self.sock.accept()`), a socket `clientConn` is created. You use this socket to communicate with the client, not `self.sock`. In your loop, `clientNameReq = self.sock.recv(10)` should be changed to `clientNameReq = clientConn.recv(10)`.

**Second one**. Having the loop corrected

```
while (1):
    clientNameReq = clientConn.recv(10)
    print("A")
```

program has no chance to go outside this loop. It's just infinite. Make sure to introduce some kind of condition here.

```
got_the_name = False
while not got_the_name:
    clientNameReq += clientConn.recv(10)
    got_the_name = foo(clientNameReq)
```

**Third one**. Please note, in the last piece of code I changed `clientNameReq =` to `clientNameReq +=`. I did it because [in TCP, message boundaries are not preserved](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html). The same thing applies to the client code in the following line `RegReqResp = self.sock.recv(1024)`

**Fourth one**. Not sure why you need `SO_REUSEADDR` option set.

---

Just on a separate note, Python has its own coding style guide: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Obviously, no one is obliged to follow it, but I think you'll find this read interesting.

Comment: Another issue is threading: It doesn't work this way. Thread subclasses need to implement a `run()` method and instances need to be `start()`ed in order to run code in a separate thread.